# vim.exe ate my system resources

Tags: windows-xp, memory, vim

Empirically, this happens the second time, the first one with multiple `cmd.exe` open and `csrss.exe` getting massively big (but I didn't save any data about it and was happy when it was over).

My memory consumption grew from normal 1,7Gb (I have 1,5 physical) to over 3Gb now, so that is so surprising to see.

I have vim cli installed as a notepad replacement and I powered up `cmd.exe`, typed `vim`. It took time to get started, I wrote a line and typed `:wq` and now I'm waiting while VM size of `vim.exe` is 1.174.496 K in task manager.

I have a 1.2ghz laptop and was annoyed of cmd.exe's scrollbuffer sizes so I set them all to maximum, like 999.

Do you think that is the problem? What else can cause such huge unexpected memory allocation ... in the end vim.exe is just an editor?

Comment: What version of vim, installed how? This isn't standard Windows software, details are needed. Have you tried to update to the latest version? Your problem might have been solved in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Though I use Vim excessively, I haven't experienced such a thing in many years. It may be due to a memory leak in Vim. You didn't mention your exact Vim version; it's best to either stick to the vanilla release version from http://www.vim.org/download.php (i.e. 7.0.046), or use a latest development snapshot and update it frequently.

But I suspect it's more likely a (buggy or badly written) plugin is to blame for this. Of course, without a way to reproducibly trigger the problem, it'll be tough to find the root cause. In this case, you should still be able to abort (`<C-c>`) the plugin processing and `:quit!` Vim. Sorry that I don't have any better advice.